# Threads and Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, task

I'm trying to open new windows form with thread and task, but this code open new windows, but do not show buttons, textfield, etc on it (form is loading)

```
private void newFomrm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NewForm a = new NewForm(param); // my Form
    Action showMethod = () => {  a.Show(); };
    Task t1 = new Task(showMethod);
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t1.Start));
    t.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `Task` at all?

Comment: I need to use both of them in my program..

Comment: @user4039853: Why do you need to use both of them in your program? Is that the requirement for the homework assignment? I see you got an answer from someone else that meets the literal reading of your question, but it's a remarkably bizarre way to show a form, when you could just call a.Show() in the Click event handler and return. If the requirement to show the form using a Task and/or Thread is more than just arbitrary busy work, you need to explain that in precise detail (and if it _is_ just arbitrary busy work, well...that's not what SO is for).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewForm a = new NewForm(); // my Form
        Action showMethod = () => {
            Invoke(new Action(() => a.Show())); 
        };
        Task t1 = new Task(showMethod);
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(t1.Start));
        t.Start(); 
    }
```

try this...you have to put the UI operation on the main thread